# Arraylist of String not being created in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to make a new user in `Firebase` having 4 fields 
1.username
2.posts
3.followers
4.following --> `ArrayList`

where following is an `ArrayList` but the last field doesn't get created in Firebase at all.

Here is the result i am getting:
[image: result]

Code for creating new user:

```
UserBean userBean = new UserBean(mUsername.toLowerCase(),0,0,new ArrayList<String>());
mUserDatabase.push().setValue(userBean);
```

My UserBean:

```
String username;
int followers,post;
ArrayList<String> following;

public UserBean() {}

public UserBean(String username, int followers, int post, ArrayList<String> following) {
    this.username = username;
    this.followers = followers;
    this.post = post;
    this.following = following;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public int getFollowers() {
    return followers;
}

public void setFollowers(int followers) {
    this.followers = followers;
}

public int getPost() {
    return post;
}

public void setPost(int post) {
    this.post = post;
}

public ArrayList<String> getFollowing() {
    return following;
}

public void setFollowing(ArrayList<String> following) {
    this.following = following;
}
```

I also tried adding the data to the `ArrayList` anyways but the data does not get added in the `Firebase`. Here is what i have tried:

```
 Query currentUserQuery = mUsersReference.orderByChild("username").equalTo(mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName().toLowerCase());
 Log.d(MainActivity.TAG,mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName().toLowerCase());


currentUserQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                                ArrayList<String> following = (ArrayList<String>) data.child("following").getValue();
                                following.add(username);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });
```

`ArrayList<String> following = (ArrayList<String>) data.child("following").getValue();` This line of code throws `NullPointerException` but it should have added the data in the list as you guys are saying the list just doesn't show up without any data. Then why does it throw `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Have you tried to add some data to your ArrayList before adding it to the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Apparently, @Vinay Avasthi is right, Firebase doesn't show an empty `ArrayList` in the database so if you are initializing your object and passing an empty `ArrayList` in your constructor then the `ArrayList` won't show up in `Firebase` which further gives you one more problem that; In future, if you want to add the data in the list, you cannot do so as it gives you the `NullPointerException` so to tackle all these problem what i had to do is pass an `ArrayList` with an empty `String` then i could show that `List` in the `firebase` and refer it easily.

```
ArrayList<String> following = new ArrayList<>();
following.add("");
UserBean userBean = new UserBean(mUsername.toLowerCase(),0,0,following);
mUserDatabase.push().setValue(userBean);
```

One more important thing to note , also pointed by @Vinay Avasthi is that you also have to set the value of the list again to your new list otherwise you would be adding the data in the list but the data won't update in the `Firebase`.

```
ArrayList<String> following = (ArrayList<String>) data.child("following").getValue();
following.add(username);
String key = data.getKey();                   
mUsersReference.child(key).child("following").setValue(following);
```

But there is still one issue though that i am facing, that in every list you will be having an empty `String` for which you have no use.

[image]

For now, i will just ignore the empty `String` while showing users their `followings`. But I think `firebase` should have created the empty `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, firebase does not create array items if there are no elements in it. If you add an element in the list, you will see it in firebase.

Comment: I tried adding the data but i am unable to push data in the arraylist in firebase. I have updated my post, please have a look at it.

Comment: After adding item to list, you have to store it again. `dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(dataSnapshot.getValue())`

Comment: `ArrayList<String> following = (ArrayList<String>) data.child("following").getValue();` This line of code throws `NullPointerException` but it should have added the data in the list as you guys are saying the list just doesn't show without any data. Then why does it throw `NullPointerException`?

Comment: The above code is only retriving the array from already queried snapshot. After you add the values to inmemory list, you have to persist it as well on firebase. For that you have to use setValue.

Comment: But how do you add the data for the first time? Not at the time of creation of list.

Comment: Look at your constructor. Populate the list there. `UserBean userBean = new UserBean(mUsername.toLowerCase(),0,0,new ArrayList<String>());`. Replace the `new ArrayList<String>()` to something like `Arrays.asList(value1, value2)`